# How do I access the raw body of a Fastify request?

Tags: javascript, node.js, fastify

As you may imagine, I'm familiar with Express, but this is the first time I'm using Fastify.

I'd like to access the *unmodified* body of a Fastify request, for signature verification of a webhook - ie, I would like to see the request as it came in, unmodified by any middleware. In Express this is often done by accessing `request.rawBody`.

**How do I access the raw body of a Fastify request?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the docs https://docs.nestjs.com/faq/raw-body

in main.ts

```
  const app = await NestFactory.create<NestFastifyApplication>(
    AppModule,
    new FastifyAdapter(),
    {
      rawBody: true,
    },
  );
```

Then in your controller

```
  async handleStripeEvent(
    @Headers('stripe-signature') signature: string,
    @Req() request: RawBodyRequest<FastifyRequest>,
  ) {
    if (!signature) {
      throw new BadRequestException('Missing stripe-signature header');
    }

    const event = await this.webhooksService.handleStripePaymentWebhook(
      signature,
      request.rawBody,
    );
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for the updated answer! Making this one official as the others (including my own) are a bit outdated now. PS. I added a missing curly to the code.

Answer (score 6):

You can also check this community plugin: https://github.com/Eomm/fastify-raw-body

If you are using Typescript & fastify/autoload, place this to plugins/rawbody.ts:

```
import fp from "fastify-plugin";

import rawbody, { RawBodyPluginOptions } from "fastify-raw-body";

export default fp<RawBodyPluginOptions>(async (fastify) => {
  fastify.register(rawbody, {
    field: "rawBody", // change the default request.rawBody property name
    global: false, // add the rawBody to every request. **Default true**
    encoding: "utf8", // set it to false to set rawBody as a Buffer **Default utf8**
    runFirst: true, // get the body before any preParsing hook change/uncompress it. **Default false**
    routes: [], // array of routes, **`global`** will be ignored, wildcard routes not supported
  });
});
```

Since `global:false` We need to configure it in the specific handler:

```
  fastify.post<{ Body: any }>(
    "/api/stripe_webhook",
    {
      config: {
        // add the rawBody to this route. if false, rawBody will be disabled when global is true
        rawBody: true,
      },
    },

    async function (request, reply) {
...
```

Then you can access raw body in the handler using `request.rawBody`

Comment: Thanks @fatihpense! Your answer is much simpler, and more keeping in line with Fastify community, than my old answer from 2 years ago so congrats I'll make this the accepted answer.

Comment: @mikemaccana Thanks for the kind words. I'm glad it was useful.

Comment: You saved my day @fatihpense thanks a lot.

Comment: @allexiusw Thanks, I'm glad it is still helping people :)

Answer (score 4):

**Note**: Fastify requests can *only* have req.body - they can't have, for example, req.body and req.rawBody like other web servers (for example, Express). This is because `addContentTypeParser()` only returns a modified `body`, it can't add anything else to the request.

Instead, in a content type parser we *only* add to one route, we make:

- `req.body.parsed` (the object, same content that would normally be in req.body)
- `req.body.raw` (the string)

See [GitHub](https://github.com/fastify/fastify/issues/707) and [the addContentTypeParser()](https://www.fastify.io/docs/master/ContentTypeParser/#body-parser) docs for more.

```
  server.addContentTypeParser(
    "application/json",
    { parseAs: "string" },
    function (req, body, done) {
      try {
        var newBody = {
          raw: body,
          parsed: JSON.parse(body),
        };
        done(null, newBody);
      } catch (error) {
        error.statusCode = 400;
        done(error, undefined);
      }
    }
  );
```

Answer (score 2):

There's an [issue on GitHub for rawBody support](https://github.com/fastify/fastify/issues/707#issuecomment-364803293)

And there's a module too: ["raw-body"](https://www.npmjs.com/package/raw-body). To use this module in Fastify:

```
const rawBody = require('raw-body')

fastify.addContentTypeParser('*', (req, done) => {
    rawBody(req, {
        length: req.headers['content-length'],
        limit: '1mb',
        encoding: 'utf8', // Remove if you want a buffer
    }, (err, body) => {
        if (err) return done(err)
        done(null, parse(body))
    })
})
```

I hope that I helped you, I'm new on fastify too

Comment: Update: I'm not sure this actually works - it parses the body raw, but doesn't add `req.rawBody` but instead replaces `body` with an unparsed body.