# Raw body verification in stripe

Tags: javascript, node.js, stripe-payments, backend, fastify

I am trying to access the raw body in Fastify for verification in Stripe. But, I am not able to do it in any way. I tried most of the solutions mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61122089/how-do-i-access-the-raw-body-of-a-fastify-request#:%7E:text=If%20you%20are%20using%20Typescript,%2F%2F%20change%20the%20default%20request.).

This is how I am registering the controller to routes.

```js
export const paymentRoutes = (app: FastifyInstance, _opts: any, done: Function) => {
app.register(rawbody, {
  field: 'rawBody',
  global: false,
  encoding: 'utf8',
  runFirst: true,
});
app.route({
  method: ['GET', 'POST'],
  url: '/webhook',
  config: {
    rawBody: true,
  },
  handler: subscriptionWebhook,
});
})
```

And this is how I am instantiating fastify server.

```js
export default class App {
  public app: any;
  public port: number;

  constructor(port ? : number) {
    this.app = fastify({
      querystringParser: (query: string) => qs.parse(query),
    });
    this.port = port || config.app.port;
    this.setup();
  }

  public setup() {
    this.app.register(helmet);
    this.app.register(cors, {
      credentials: true,
      origin: ['https://localhost:3000'],
      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': true,
      'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'PUT,GET,POST,DELETE,PATCH',
    });

    //Content Parser : that I cannot remove from every route. Is there any way to add 2 different parsers one on specific route and other one on rest of the routes

    this.app.addContentTypeParser(
      'application/json', {
        parseAs: 'string',
        bodyLimit: 120000000
      },
      (_: any, body: any, done: any) => {
        try {
          const json = JSON.parse(body as string);
          done(null, json);
        } catch (e: any) {
          e.statusCode = 400;
          done(e);
        }
      },
    );

  }
```

```
stripe.webhooks.constructEvent(body, sig, endpointSecret);
```

I tried passing rawBody and body but it is always throwing me this error.

> reason: StripeSignatureVerificationError: No signatures found matching the expected signature for payload. Are you passing the raw request body you received from Stripe?

Comment: You can make use of the `onRequest` hook to modify the request object and store the raw body as a separate property.

Comment: can you please elaborate @LightningMcQueen? I tried adding  this in setup but couldn't see a log.
this.app.onRequest((request: any, reply: any) => {
            console.log('on request');
        });

Comment: [See this JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/aj28knvs/).

Comment: Why did you add the content type parser that run a json.parse instead of using the default one? I think it impact the signature check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By accessing the request inside addContentTypeParser, I added a check based on the incoming URL to decide whether to apply parser or not.